# Сохранить ключи массива в foreach

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Как сохранить ключи исходного массива в новый массив? Мне это нужно для объединения в другой итоговый массив (не получается все данные вытащить в одном API запросе) с последующей публикации его на WWW

```
foreach ($ISgetSipDevice as $value) {
  $item = $value['ISPoolID'];
  $arrayValue[$item][] = $value['ISPoolID'];
  $arrayValue[$item][] = $value['ISconfigDevType'];
  $arrayValue[$item][] = $value['ISDevMac'];
  $arrayValue[$item][] = $value['ISDevAddr']['Xipv4Address'];
}
```

Сейчас это выглядит так, и в целом меня это устраивает

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 7942
            [2] => 001D.70FD.71F5
            [3] => 172.19.18.25
        )
```

Но мне интересно, можно сделать вот такой вывод?

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ISPoolID] => 1
            [ISconfigDevType] => 7942
            [ISDevMac] => 001D.70FD.71F5
            [Xipv4Address] => 172.19.18.25
        )
```

Последний ключ (Xipv4Address) возможно так не получится, но можно и виде массива, это уже не принципиально.

Comment: Так пробовали?  `$arrayValue[$item]['ISPoolID'] = $value['ISPoolID'];`, `$arrayValue[$item]['ISconfigDevType'] = $value['ISconfigDevType'];` и т.д

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как мне подсказали в коментариях (Pashok спасибо!), надо делать так

```
foreach ($ISgetSipDevice as $value) {
  $item = $value['ISPoolID'];
  $arrayValue[$item]['ISPoolID'] = $value['ISPoolID'];
  $arrayValue[$item]['ISconfigDevType'] = $value['ISconfigDevType'];
  $arrayValue[$item]['ISDevMac'] = $value['ISDevMac'];
  $arrayValue[$item]['Xipv4Address'] = $value['ISDevAddr']['Xipv4Address'];
}
```